# Android Automation Error Displayed: "Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent"

Tags: java, android, selenium-webdriver, automation, appium-android

Tested multiple android native applications using appium/selenium automation script but none of the applications are getting opened and getting the following error message

> Stderr: 'Security exception: Permission Denial: starting Intent from null (pid=20930, uid=2000) not exported from uid 10178'

The Desired capabilities are set correctly but none of the apps are getting opened.

```
DesiredCapabilities caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
        caps.setCapability("deviceName", "Mobile");
        caps.setCapability("udid", "520042c3b5e5"); 
        caps.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        caps.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.0.0"); 
        caps.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
        caps.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.web.MShopWebGatewayActivity");
        caps.setCapability("noReset", "true");          

        //Instantiate Appium Driver
        try 
        {
            AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://0.0.0.0:4723/wd/hub"), caps);
        } 
        catch (MalformedURLException e) 
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }
```

Amazon mobile application should get opened but Security exception: Permission Denial error message is displayed.

Tried for other native apps by changing app package and activity and still getting the same error for all the apps tried.

There are few solutions online which says to edit an export field in `AndroidManifest.xml`. Where this File would be found?

Appium Version - 1.10.0
Java - JDK 1.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get this kind of error when you try to launch the appActivity that is not main Activity.

> You must put the main appActivity in your desired capability.

I also get the similar problem when the developer added the splash screen in the app and changed the main app activity.

Comment: Thank you Suban. Could you please guide me in getting the main app activity.

Comment: you can use **adb shell dumpsys package | grep -i "  (enter package name) " | grep Activity** command to find the main activity. you need to run your app after writing the script

Comment: Thank you so much. I opened the app in android studio in debug mode to find main activity from AndroidManifest.xml. The issue issue resolved now.

Answer (score 1):

From the [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element?hl=es) this what the exported attribute does if:

- **android:exported = true**  -> The broadcast receiver is able to receive messages from sources outside the app
- **android:exported = false**  ->broadcast receiver is only able to receive message from the app itself

You can add the `exported` attribute inside the `<activity>` element tag in the AndroidManifest.xml file like below:

```
 <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true"> 
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

Comment: I am not able to locate the AndroidManifest.xml. could you please guide me in locating the file? Should this update be done for each app separately or in a single common file which will be applicable for all the applications.

Comment: The `AndroidManifest.xml` file is located at the root of every app project. This needs to be done for each app separately.

Comment: Thank you Bryan. Could that file be accessed from command prompt using adb command or is there some other way way to do that? I am yet to make an online search on this but still requesting you as well.

Comment: This would be appropriate if the app was yours, since you could find it inside your project. I have not tried this with an application from another developer since you would have recompile. However, if you have the `.apk` file in a computer, you could rename it to a `.zip` file and extract the files there. After, you will see the `AndroidManifest.xml` file. Hope this helps

Comment: If the answer helped you, kindly consider checking the green check to help others seeking the same

Comment: Thank you again. This issue is not specific to one single app but finding it on all the common applications like amazon, whatsapp, linkedin that are already installed in my mobile. I tried connected an alternate mobile and also from emulator but still getting the same error. I am a learner and not sure where i am going wrong.

Comment: It will be difficult to do it on apps that are not yours, since you will have to go through the whole process of recompiling which is definitely not permitted. However, if this is only for test purposes you could go ahead.

Comment: Hi Bryan, the issue is resolved now and it was related to splash/main activity in the apps. Thank you so much for your support.